# jquery image transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a button in a website that I'm making for a college project (Website that sells music). Im using a buy button which looks like the one from Apple's app store:

[image1 http://ryanholder.co.uk/img/buy_button_5.99.png](http://ryanholder.co.uk/img/buy_button_5.99.png)

[image2 http://ryanholder.co.uk/img/ibutton_buynow.png](http://ryanholder.co.uk/img/ibutton_buynow.png)

I was yondering if anybody knows some JQuery which I could use, or if you could create some, so that i can click on the First image and it transitions to the secound image. Kinda like if you click on it in the actual iTunes app store.

*And if you can a way to transition back to the previous image

And before you say dude this is obviously copyright. I am ony using this design for a college project, not an actual website ;)

Thanks in advance :)!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my_button').click(function(){
   if ($(this).css('background-image') == 'first_image'){
      $(this).css('background-image', 'second_image')
   } else {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'first_image')
   }
})
```

Comment: I added this:
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#buybutton').click(function(){
   if ($(this).css('background-image') == '/img/album_covers/buy_button_5.99.png'){
      $(this).css('background-image', '/img/album_covers/ibutton_buynow.png')
   } else {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'img/album_covers/buy_button_5.99.png')
   }
})
</script>

and my div is called buybutton

but it dident work, not sure what im doing wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

http://designbeep.com/2010/05/13/25-very-detailed-jquery-image-and-content-slider-tutorials/.  Being a college project we wouldn't want to take all the fun out of learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to put both images into one file and then simply change the visible coordinates with jquery.
Digging up example. BRB

Comment: this will do an unnecessary load of image(s)